# Need to change how \pagenote typesets the note number

Tags: formatting, endnotes, pagenote

I'm trying to get the `pagenote` package to display the note numbers as

```
\textbf{ \blue{ \big[ \roman{ notenum } \big] } }
```

I've redefined the `\notenumintext` as follows:

```
\renewcommand*{\notenumintext}[1]{\textbf{\blue \big[\roman{pagenote}\big]}}
```

and it displays exactly what I want.  The .ent file appears to encode the correct information.

But, a similar redefinition of `\noteenuminnotes` produces errors or strange output (like the correct format, but all the note numbers are the same).

Right now, the document is written using the article document class, with `\usepackage[page]{pagenote}` loaded (among other things).

Is this a simple case of not really understanding how the `renewcommand` works with counters?

Yes, I've read the documentation many times as well as numerous discussion boards.  Most of the documentations say things like, "this can be redefined"  but don't tell you how to do it.  Since I'm relatively new to this type of LaTeXing, it's a bit frustrating.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) A tip: If you [indent lines by 4 spaces](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1192/how-do-i-mark-code-blocks) or [enclose words in backticks `\``](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/863/how-do-i-mark-inline-code), they'll be marked as code, as can be seen in my edit. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: @doncherry:  Thanks!  I went to edit the post, and it appears the code is now formatted accordingly.

Comment: You're welcome `:-)`. I formatted your code, users with >2000 reputation can [edit other users' posts](http://tex.stackexchange.com/privileges/edit).

Comment: I'm trying to come up with minimal sample code to post.

Comment: The renewcommand doesn't work with counters. That is to say, when you renew a command you change it's definition. If the original command increased a counter and your replacement does not, then the counter won't be increased anymore. I suggest you have a look at how the command is defined in the pagenote package. This probably wont be straightforward, but trying to figure it out will increase your understanding, if you get stuck you can modify the question with your research and people will probably be able to help.

Comment: I appreciate the suggestion.  I've spent the last two days looking at the pagenote documentation -- including the code at the bottom.  What I have posted above is the result of that effort.

It is true that I didn't know that about \renewcommand and counters, so I'm happy to go back to the documentation and puzzle it out some more!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you would like the note number in the page notes area to be displayed in bold, blue, numbering style lowercase-roman, and in a font size that's one "step" larger than "normal", where "normal" is the font size of the main body of the text (usually 10pt, 11pt, or 12pt). If this understanding is correct, you may want to try the code in the following MWE. Observe that the redefinition of the rendering of the note's "number" into lowercase-roman format is undertaken separately from the redefinitions of the `\notenumintext` and `\notenuminnotes` macros.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor,pagenote}
\makepagenote
\renewcommand\thepagenote{\roman{pagenote}}
\renewcommand{\notenumintext}[1]{%  default setting: "\textsuperscript{#1}}"
    \textsuperscript{\normalsize\bfseries\color{blue}#1}}
\renewcommand{\notenuminnotes}[1]{% default setting: "{\normalfont #1.} }"
    {\large\bfseries\color{blue}[#1]} }
\begin{document}
\section{Some random text}
Abcdefgh.\pagenote{Some random thoughts.}

\printnotes
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I gave it a try.  It didn't compile, and said
 ./filename.ent:2: Missing number, treated as zero.
 <to be read again>
\c@1
l.2 \noteentry{1}{}{text}{17}

If I replace the #1 with the static `pagenote` then it compiles, but all the note numbers on the notes page have the same value (the largest value of the pagenote counter).  The note numbers in the text look correct.

Comment: I've rewritten my answer, this time with a full MWE.

Comment: I'm really glad it worked. Feel free to accept/check-mark my answer any time. ;-)

Comment: Ahh...I knew I was supposed to do something official to close out the discussion.  I clicked on the check mark above - and thanks for the nudge.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of applying `\roman` to the argument of `\notenuminnotes`, redefine `\thepagenote`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{color}

\usepackage{pagenote}
\makepagenote

\renewcommand{\notenuminnotes}[1]{%
    {\large\bfseries\color{blue}[#1]}\enskip
}
\renewcommand{\thepagenote}{\roman{pagenote}}

\begin{document}

\section{foo}

Some text.\pagenote{A pagenote.}

\printnotes

\end{document}
```

Comment: I think this is basically what Mico mentioned below -- I just happened to see his post first.  Thank you for the help!